# ML 350 has 1 second strange noise right after cold start

Tags: engine, noise, mercedes-benz, cold-start

I have Mercedes ML350 (2011) and this winter I noticed that it started making weird noise right after cold start, I'm almost sure that this isn't timing chain (I know how broken timing chain sounds).

Here's the video where you can here that noise: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bt85i0mp4Lo

Any idea what's the issue?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! At what point in the video does the strange noise occur? What is it we are listening for?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 at 0:08